# How to set ScheduledExecutorService to end when user quits program?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, alert, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a ScheduledExecutorService that I pass a Runnable to. If the Enemy object that the thread is for dies, I end the thread with `.shutDown()`, which works just fine. However, if the user quits the program, the thread still runs. How I can shut it down when this happens?

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 2,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("SHOOT");
    }
};
```

Right now I'm overriding the `stop()`method in my Main from Application.

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Exit ?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    alert.show();

    if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {
        //this works if put outside of alert
        BlueSlime.scheduler.shutdown();
        super.stop();
    }

    if(alert.getResult() == ButtonType.NO){
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

By making the scheduler static, I can shut it down by referencing BlueSLime from Main. This will shut it down, but is there a better way? Also the Alert doesn't really work, when I close the program, the Alert box shows for like half a second, and disappears and leaves the threads running again.

Comment: It's too late to create new GUI elements in the `stop` method since it's called when the JavaFX platform is shutting down (it's the right place to shut down executors though). It should be used to clean up resources only. BTW: There is a better way than using a static executor: passing the executor to the classes where it's used in a non-static way. As for a way to make the shutdown more elegant: It's possible to pass a `ThreadFactory` to the method creating the executor. You using a `ThreadFactory` that returns daemon threads prevents the service from keeping the app running.

Comment: I see, but what do you mean with passing the executor to the classes where it's used in a non-static way? I spawn a BlueSlime in my GameLogic class where it is is updated/drawn/cleared. Would I have to reference the GameLogic class instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a shutdown hook. That's a brute force method. Instead make your threads daemon threads. Just add the following piece of code to your class

```
private static class DaemonThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    }
}
```

and then change your first line of code above to

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new DaemonThreadFactory());
```

That's it.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for simplifying it for me! I had seen that example on here while researching, but it looked kind of complicated... nevertheless, is the way I did it in the `stop()` method of the Main class also considered brute force?

Comment: You just don't have to do that anymore with the daemon threads.

Answer (score 0):

Add shutdown hook like this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(scheduler::shutdown))`